# RedisMessageListenerContainer : Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms

Tags: spring-boot, redis

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageSubscriber());
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), topic());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessagePublisher redisPublisher() {
        return new MessagePublisherImpl(redisTemplate(), topic());
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelTopic topic() {
        return new ChannelTopic("pubsub:queue");
    }

}
```

for Docker-container

```
bind 0.0.0.0
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
loglevel notice
logfile /data/log/redis-server.log
databases 16
always-show-logo yes
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /data/bases
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
slave-lazy-flush no
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble no
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
  image: redis
  container_name: redis
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - //projects/spring-data-redis-example/src/main/resources/docker/redis/storage:/opt/redis/data/bases
    - //projects/spring-data-redis-example/src/main/resources/docker/redis/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    - //projects/spring-data-redis-example/src/main/resources/docker/redis/log/redis-server.log:/opt/redis/logs/redis-server.log
  ports:
    - 6379:6379
```

The docker-machine has IP = 192.168.99.109

- application.properties

```
spring.redis.host=192.168.99.109
spring.redis.port=6379
```

- pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>redis</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <version.mapstruct>1.3.0.Final</version.mapstruct>
        <version.apache.maven.plugins>3.8.1</version.apache.maven.plugins>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.apache.maven.plugins}</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

> 2020-08-09 12:57:07.083 ERROR 129008 --- [edisContainer-1]
> o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer  : Connection failure
> occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms 2020-08-09
> 12:57:11.034  INFO 129008 --- [           main]
> redis.RedisExampleApplication            : Started
> RedisExampleApplication in 8.344 seconds (JVM running for 9.297)
> 2020-08-09 12:57:13.083 ERROR 129008 --- [edisContainer-2]
> o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer  : Connection failure

When I try to save data into base Redis, I get an exception..

[image]

**Update-1**

[image]

- pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Update_2**

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }

    /**
    * <b>MessageSubscriber</b> is  a implementation
     * of {@link org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener}
     * The MessageSubscriber is developed in the app
     * @return
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageSubscriber());
    }


    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {

        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), topic());
        return container;
    }

    /**
  <b>MessagePublisherImpl</b> is a implementation of {@link    redis.service.message.MessagePublisher}
     * The MessagePublisher is developed in the application
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    MessagePublisher redisPublisher() {

        return new MessagePublisherImpl(redisTemplate(), topic());
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelTopic topic() {
        return new ChannelTopic("pubsub:queue");
    }
}
```

- pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>-->


    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but, there is an error:

[image]

In debug mode :

[image]

Why is "localhost"  ?

I pointed (**192.168.99.100**):

```
spring.redis.host=192.168.99.100
spring.redis.port=6379
```

How can I customize - IP of redis server into config file ?

**Update 3**

**It's working.**

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.database}")
    private int indexDataBase;

    @Bean
    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();

        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(this.hostName);
  
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(this.indexDataBase);

        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory =
                new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);


        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {

        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();

        template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());

        template.setKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
        template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));

        return template;
    }

    /**
     * <b>MessageSubscriber</b> is  a implementation
     * of {@link org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener}
     * The MessageSubscriber is developed in the app
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageSubscriber());
    }


    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {

        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), topic());
        return container;
    }

    /**
     * <b>MessagePublisherImpl</b> is a implementation of {@link redis.service.message.MessagePublisher}
     * The MessagePublisher is developed in the application
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    MessagePublisher redisPublisher() {

        return new MessagePublisherImpl(redisTemplate(), topic());
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelTopic topic() {
        return new ChannelTopic("pubsub:queue");
    }
}
```

I have configured the configuration file, but when I start it, I get an error about a failed connection. Redis is running in docker.

Do anyone have any ideas how to correct this ?

[image]

Comment: It will be pretty hard to help if you don't provide any information about Redis container. I don't think there is any problem without your code. Try a telnet to confirm your Redis is accessible from outside its container

Comment: Cyril G.. I have added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You config works for me. Not sure why.

Still, you can try [Lettuce](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/).

Swap your config file for this and see if works.

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
    return template;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(new RedisMessageSubscriber());
}

@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
    final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
    container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), topic());
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessagePublisher redisPublisher() {
    return new RedisMessagePublisher(redisTemplate(), topic());
}

@Bean
ChannelTopic topic() {
    return new ChannelTopic("pubsub:queue");
}
```

}

Comment: Excuse me, How should I understand the frase - 'you can try lettuce'. But, I try out that .

Comment: Lettuce is a preferred alternative to Jedis, thus used as default Redis client in Spring Data Redis.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to answer. I download dependencies in parts, sometimes manually ( the Internet is blocked in our country). Can you tell me what else you need (see a picture above). Some dependencies aren't imported.

Comment: It's included in        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency> , not sure why you're not getting it. Also you should comment out         <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>. Since with Lettuce, you don't need jedis client anymore.  Also, as someone from China, which has blocked Internet too, I suggest you use a VPN when developing.

Comment: I found a mistakes (see above)

Comment: I found a decision.